# Show an image partially in a circular progress area

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass

I have an image as shown below. I want to show the image partially, based on the input value in AngularJS. If the input value is 0 then we only have to show the black mask on it. If the value is 50, then we can show half of the image on the right side and half back background on the left side. So basically the image visible part should be based on the input value.

I have tried with a few circular progress bars like https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar and https://github.com/mathewbyrne/angular-progress-arc and also with some CSS, but it was not working properly. Can some one help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* overlay the image with an SVG element, create an arc, and set its values via JavaScript. The SVG element would look something like this:

```
<svg>
    <path d="Mpoint1 Lpoint2 AcircleRadius 0 1 0 point3 Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" fill="black"/> 
</svg>
```

Where you should replace

- `point1` with the coordinates of the center point of the circle
- `point2` with the coordinates of the top point of the circle
- `circleRadius` with the x-radius and y-radius of the circle (which are the same in your case, as it's a circle)
- `point3` with the coordinates of the point you want the arc to end (so, that would be the point at the bottom right in your picture).

Then, you can use simple CSS to position this SVG element precisely on top of the image. Then, you can perform calculations with the JavaScript and simply set the `d` attribute on the SVG element to the correct

For more information on SVG paths, check: [SVG Paths](http://pandaqi.com/Website/svg-paths)

To see a working example, with a JavaScript function that automatically creates the right arc based on input value, check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pandaqi/gLomh1qn/)

Comment: I tried this http://plnkr.co/edit/IV3JANaAePO9eU32yhAw?p=preview. But stuck to adjust in the exact way. Will you please take a look at it.

Comment: I've copied your code and updated it so that it works, and added some comments. You can find it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pandaqi/gLomh1qn/)

Comment: If i change the value `80,40` to `80,60` the positioning is also changing slightly. Can it be fixed, so that the positioning will not change and only the visible part will change.

Comment: Yes, do you know anything about circle mathematics? Because, the point `80,60` is *not* on the circle, so naturally things don't look the way you want. I've updated the fiddle with a JavaScript function that automatically converts the input values to the right circle coordinates for you :)

Comment: Can u share the updated fiddle link? In the older link, i am unable to see any JS function. And also i was only changing the values which you mentioned in the  comments, to show the percentage of the image.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, apparently something went wrong. Find the updated fiddle here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pandaqi/gLomh1qn/)

Comment: Great! In that case, please upvote the answer and mark it as correct, so that other people with the same problem can find it.

Comment: Could you please change the 
`<script>setCoordinates(40, 00);</script>`
to 
`<script>setCoordinates(40, 20);</script>`
in the fiddle, so that it will show some part of the image.